# Cases after connectives

Tags: падежи, существительные

In a given sentences, does the noun after a connective go into the same case of the noun before the connective or does it go into a different case.

For example:
Я должнá звони́ть матери и (тётя) пóсле лéкции

In this example, мать goes into the genitive case, would тетя also go into the genitive or would it go into a different case?

Comment: Пóсле лéкции  я должна позвонить и матери, и тёте, и бабушке, и дедушке, и брату, и сестре.////Пóсле лéкции  Виктор  должен позвонить и матери, и тёте, и бабушке, и дедушке, и брату, и сестре.

Answer (score 6):

Sure, both nouns should be in the dative case not genitive.

звонить (кому?) матери и тёте.